# changing desktop background in windows 10 via nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows

I have a small project tha change wallpaper after 2 days, I'm using nodejs 14 and ff-nappi.

I have this code:

```
const ffi = require("ffi-napi");
const ref = require("ref-napi");
const wchar_t = require("ref-wchar-napi");

var wchar_string = wchar_t.string;

const lib = ffi.Library("user32", {
  SystemParametersInfoW: ["int", ["uint", "uint", wchar_string, "uint"]],
});

const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
const SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

export function setWallpaper(pathString: string) {
  const path = ref.alloc(wchar_string, pathString);
  lib.SystemParametersInfoW(
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0,
    path,
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE
  );
}
```

After running this my wallpaper went black.

Comment: Valid full path to wallpaper? bmp or jpg?

Comment: yes I validate the path to wallpaper and I tried jpg and png

Comment: Passing in 0 or an empty string as the path probably removes the wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

`ffi-napi` hadnles conversion of the path string to wchar_string, so the conversion using `ref-napi` is redundant.

The whole snippet that worked for me (I skipped passing flags as well):

```
const ffi = require("ffi-napi");
const wchar_t = require("ref-wchar-napi");

var wchar_string = wchar_t.string;

const lib = ffi.Library("user32", {
  SystemParametersInfoW: ["int", ["uint", "uint", wchar_string, "uint"]],
});

const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;

export function setWallpaper(pathString: string) {
  lib.SystemParametersInfoW(
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0,
    pathString,
    0
  );
}
```